# Access dir-locals variables with elisp

Tags: directory-local-variables

I have following `.dir-locals.el` file in my project directory:

```
((nil . ((logbook . "todo.org"))))
```

and following function:

```lisp
(defun project-switch (&optional project-dir)
  "switch to project"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((project-dir (if project-dir
                         project-dir
                        (project-prompt-project-dir)))
         (default-directory project-dir))

    (message "%s " default-directory)
    (hack-dir-local-variables-non-file-buffer)

      (if (boundp 'logbook)
          (message "logbooK: %s" logbook)
        (message "nope"))))
```

If I run the function, it messages me `nope` even though the `.dir-locals.el` file is present.

EDIT: updated code with feedback. It still messages me `nope`. If I manually open a file in the project directory it prints it just fine.

Comment: Note to improve your code : you can avoid using two `let`s by using `let*` instead. See [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42449/what-does-let-let-asterisk-mean-in-elisp).

Answer (score 3):

By default, directory-local variables are processed for file-visiting buffers and not too many other kinds of buffer -- anything else needs to be handled explicitly (using `hack-dir-local-variables-non-file-buffer`).

So if you didn't run your command from a file-visiting buffer (or had not reverted that buffer since changing the `.dir-locals.el` file), then it likely wouldn't have contained those local values.

Comment: Thanks but it still messages me `nope`. If I manually open a file in the project directory it prints it just fine.

Comment: I tried your code and called `(project-switch DIR)` for a DIR with your `.dir-locals.el` and it messaged me the `todo.org` filename.